# Spell check in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, spell-checking

Is anyone aware of any workarounds to do spell check on the text in PowerBI dashboard? The feature does not seem to be there. The only way I know is to first copy the text into Word or PPT make sure the grammar and spelling is correct and then paste it into PowerBI but it is a very tedious process.

Answer (score 6):

Just go to another page and come back to the one where you see red underline for spell check. Voila!

I know its weird but it works.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct approach to achieve this, however, you can try the following:

1. Use this API service and create a wrapper API: [Spell Check API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/Bing-Web-Search/)
2. Create a function in Power BI query editor which takes text as input and calls the API 
   to check the spellings
3. Create a new custom column where you can invoke this function to perform the spell check.